# Opencart Filter Button Enter in Product List and Category List

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

I recently create a function for filter category at admin page. But when I press 'enter' button, appears popup to delete. What I want is when I press 'enter' key, it does the `filter()` function just like at product page.

I already add these code at bottom line:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function filter() {
    url = 'index.php?route=catalog/category&token=<?php echo $token; ?>';

    var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

    if (filter_name) {
        url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
    }

    location = url;
}
//--></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#form input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        filter();
    }
});
//--></script>
```

But still, when I press Enter, it return confirm of delete although the filter still running. Anyone know why in this page can't be like at product page? because the code are same.

Comment: Could you please open up the dev tools in Chrome and find what code asks you to confirm delete (look for text in all code in the console tab and press control + shift + f). You can set a breakpoint there and inspect the stack. I'm sure you'll find some code adding an event listener to that key event. You can add multiple listeners to one event.

Comment: Hello, There's nothing on console log.

Comment: I don't know where the delete confirmation comes from. Is it from opencart or from a JavaScript framework. Is it a modal dialog or native JavaScript confirm?  You can however see the text it displays and could use chrome dev tools to find the code. It would help to solve the problem if you can identify what creates the conformation. My comment was not about just looking at the console but look for something like "delete" and identify the code opening the conformation. Set a breakpoint there and check out the call stack. You should be able to find what code adds the event listener.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, but there's nothing about this confirmation. FYI, opencart header.tpl has this script to be running on every page that call delete button. That's why it works on both category and product page. But in product page, when I hit 'enter' button, it run the script `filter()` but in category page it run both `filter` and `delete` button, the codes are same...

Comment: Maybe you can add a custom button and not use the delete button for filter? https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=65494 I don't know about opencart or how you implemented filter so not sure if this is of any help.

Comment: Hello, that's not relevance link for my problem. I'm still wondering this problem, hope someone has same problem. But thanks for trying to answer

Comment: If the delete conformation is caused by form submitting you could try the following: `e.preventDefault();filter()` but probably the delete handler is called first. If that is the case you need to find the code that handles "submit", remove the handler `$("#form")off("submit")` and manually call the handler for submit yourself.

Comment: @HMR whoa... works like magic.... thank you... please wrote down on answer so I can mark this problem solved

Comment: Good to know, I have added it as an answer. Please let me know if you need more help. You can post the question as opencart specific question for user defined actions, maybe that will get a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pressing enter submits a form that is meant to delete the item, maybe it is possible to create a custom action but if you do not want to delete the item you cancel submitting the form that triggers delete action with:

```
...
e.preventDefault();
filter();
```

If the delete handler is called first you need to find the code that handles "submit", remove the handler

```
$("#form")off("submit")
  .on("submit",x => {
    //check if e.target is delete button and if it is
    //  then call the delete function.
  })
;
```

And manually call the handler for submit yourself (if you also want a certain action to delete the form (like a button called delete)

Comment: so finally my code is like these: `if (e.keyCode == 13) { e.preventDefault(); filter(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name=\'filter_name\']').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        filter();
    }
});
//--></script>
```

Comment: still same... I think the real problem is it runs the post method before the script